# How do I change content of ComboFieldEditor?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to change the values on one `ComboFieldEditor` depending on another `ComboFieldEditor` in an eclipse plugin. E.g. if the user changes the `package`, different classes need to be populated in the second `ComboFieldEditor`. The `ComboFieldEditor` class does not seem to to have a way to change the items on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a SmartComboFieldEditor class to allow me to elegantly get and set the value of a ComboFieldEditor using the backing data store behind the scenes.

```
package wat.core.plugin;

import org.eclipse.jface.preference.ComboFieldEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class SmartComboFieldEditor extends ComboFieldEditor {

    public SmartComboFieldEditor(String name, String labelText, String[][] entryNamesAndValues, Composite parent) {
        super(name, labelText, entryNamesAndValues, parent);
    }

    public String getSelectedValue()
    {
        doStore();
        return getPreferenceStore().getString(getPreferenceName());
    }

    public void setSelectedValue(String newValue)
    {
        getPreferenceStore().setValue(getPreferenceName(), newValue);
        doLoad();
    }
}
```

Then you can override the propertyChange and performOK methods like so:

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
  super.propertyChange(event);
  if (event.getSource() == combo1)
  {
    if (combo1.getSelectedValue().equals("Some Value"))
    {
      combo2.setSelectedValue("Some Other Value");
    }
  }
}
```