# ComboFieldEditor. Dynamically changing the values

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, preferences, fieldeditor

I am working on an eclipse RCP project. As I was going through the walkthroughs I came across preference page and started working around it.

Now I need to change the values of the `ComboFieldEditor` dynamically. As in when I make a selection on a `TextFieldEditor` the values of the `ComboFieldEditor` must change. I tried searching for an answer and even tried one of the solutions I found on Stack Overflow, but I always ended up with `NullPointerException`. Can someone help me in this regard?

Technically I want to change the values in the `ComboFieldEditor` dynamically. As in, when a listener is triggered I want to put new values in my combobox. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665906/how-do-i-change-content-of-combofieldeditor) solution but I kept getting a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I think you should post some more details to receive an answer (code, stack-trace, links, etc)...

Comment: I have edited the post. There is nothing much specific needed here. I just want to set values to a combofieldeditor for a preference page. I know its something silly, but I am just not able to pull it out. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This is something that I did for the time being.
I created a class named CustomComboFieldEditor and added all the methods present in the ComboFieldEditor. I changed the methods that helped to input the values in the combo box. Works fine for me as of now.
I am sure its not the prettiest of all ways and I bet I would be crucified for this solution, but time and situation forced me into using it. Anyother way would be appreciated.

Thanks :)